# How to build dynamic URL string for REST API endpoint call?

Tags: python, python-requests, rest

My question is about Python code to consume existing REST APIs. The script is based on [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

Let say, we have the following base URL:

```
www.something.com/search/countries/{country_code}/cities/{city_code}/
```

In order to ignore URL Encoding we assume that codes are numeric.

It seems that `format` is a perfect method to replace "place holders" with actual values.

```
URL.format(country_code = ..., city_code-... )
```

Is this *pythonic* enough?

Answer (score 1):

I think that `.format` is a perfectly fine way to do that, but it's not super readable. You can use Python f-strings to make that more readable like:

```
country_code = 'foo'
city_code = 'bar'
url = f'www.something.com/search/countries/{country_code}/cities/{city_code}/'
```

The `f` will tell Python to interpolate the values inside the curly brackets with the variables defined above.